# python: are sets ordered or unordered?

Tags: python

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) clearly says sets are unordered, but this bit of code:

`{5,2,3,7,7,5,2,3}`

Yields:

`set([2, 3, 5, 7])`

Iterating through `{5,2,3,7,7,5,2,3}` also displays the numbers in order.

So which is it: ordered or unordered? Clarification appreciated.

Comment: They don't *maintain* order. The order the elements are iterated over is entirely down to implementation details and should not be relied upon.

Comment: Try `{1, 2, 3, 88}`.

Comment: The order of sets is implementation-dependent. So it could be that in your implementation, sets are ordered, but not in another, and maybe not also the next time you will try